# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory?

Tags: python

i want code for extract url from photo but error FileNotFound don`t stop show me 
input:

```
 `from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

from pytesseract import image_to_string

from pytesseract import image_to_boxes

im = Image.open("oic.png")
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('temp2.jpg')
text = image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.jpg'))
print(text)`
```

outPut:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\Project\***********\Exstract url form photo\test tow.py", line 170, in <module>
    text = image_to_string(Image.open('temp2.jpg'))
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 346, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 349, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\fahad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 262, in run_and_get_output
    with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\fahad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_mizb9wo_.txt'
```

can you help me ??.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you already installed all the dependencies and libraries.

`tesseract`, `image` and `pytesseract`

After that you need to put the full path for your image. For example, let's assume that your image is in `/Users/Desktop`. See the example below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

from pytesseract import image_to_string

from pytesseract import image_to_boxes

im = Image.open("/Users/Desktop/oic.png")
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('/Users/Desktop/temp2.jpg')
text = image_to_string(Image.open('/Users/Desktop/temp2.jpg'))
print(text)
```

This is why you got the error `File not found`. Just tested the code here and everything works fine.